# Manjaro: Gnome Tweak Failed to register: Timeout was reached

Tags: gnome3, manjaro

Manjaro: Gnome 3.34.2

Gnome Tweaks initially worked without issue, but even upon rebooting it still will not launch. The only thing that was done after it's installation and before it stopped working was an attempt to uninstall unrelated applications through Gnome Software Center which did not work, I don't know if that's related or not.

From other similar questions I've seen regarding this issue with other applications, it isn't running in the background already and hanging.

This is also printed out in journalctl every time I attempt to launch:

```
Process 4894 (epiphany-search) of user 1000 dumped core.

   Stack trace of thread 4894:
   #0  0x00007fa4f931cf2e malloc (libc.so.6)
   #1  0x00007fa4f84348da g_malloc (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #2  0x00007fa4f850bdbb g_type_interfaces (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
   #3  0x00007fa4f8520f87 g_signal_newv (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
   #4  0x00007fa4f851e2fa g_signal_new_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
   #5  0x00007fa4f8521f6e g_signal_new (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
   #6  0x00007fa4f91a7eaf n/a (libephymisc.so)
   #7  0x00007fa4f8510e72 g_type_class_ref (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
   #8  0x00007fa4f852e588 g_object_new_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
   #9  0x00007fa4f852ec8a g_object_new (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
   #10 0x00007fa4f91a9e5e ephy_history_service_new (libephymisc.so)
   #11 0x00005614c2c970b5 ephy_embed_shell_get_global_history_service (epiphany-search-provider)
   #12 0x00005614c2c971e9 n/a (epiphany-search-provider)
   #13 0x00007fa4f8511340 g_type_create_instance (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
   #14 0x00007fa4f852d766 n/a (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
   #15 0x00007fa4f852e319 g_object_new_valist (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
   #16 0x00007fa4f852ec8a g_object_new (libgobject-2.0.so.0)
   #17 0x00005614c2c7d0e6 n/a (epiphany-search-provider)
   #18 0x00007fa4f92b9153 __libc_start_main (libc.so.6)
   #19 0x00005614c2c7d1ae n/a (epiphany-search-provider)

   Stack trace of thread 4959:
   #0  0x00007fa4f93869ef __poll (libc.so.6)
   #1  0x00007fa4f843c120 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #2  0x00007fa4f843c1f1 g_main_context_iteration (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #3  0x00007fa4f843c242 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #4  0x00007fa4f8418bb1 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #5  0x00007fa4f2d434cf start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
   #6  0x00007fa4f93912d3 __clone (libc.so.6)

   Stack trace of thread 4958:
   #0  0x00007fa4f2d49f7a pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (libpthread.so.0)
   #1  0x00007fa4f4ec2722 _ZN7bmalloc9Scavenger13threadRunLoopEv (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #2  0x00007fa4f4ec286a _ZN7bmalloc9Scavenger16threadEntryPointEPS0_ (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #3  0x00007fa4f1633ee4 execute_native_thread_routine (libstdc++.so.6)
   #4  0x00007fa4f2d434cf start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
   #5  0x00007fa4f93912d3 __clone (libc.so.6)

   Stack trace of thread 5024:
   #0  0x00007fa4f2d49f7a pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (libpthread.so.0)
   #1  0x00007fa4f4eb4bd6 _ZN3WTF15ThreadCondition9timedWaitERNS_5MutexENS_8WallTimeE (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #2  0x00007fa4f4e504c5 _ZN3WTF10ParkingLot21parkConditionallyImplEPKvRKNS_12ScopedLambdaIFbvEEERKNS3_IFvvEEERKNS_24TimeWit>
   #3  0x00007fa4f4e53c5d _ZN3WTF5sleepENS_7SecondsE (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #4  0x00007fa4f5be0556 n/a (libwebkit2gtk-4.0.so.37)
   #5  0x00007fa4f4e54909 _ZN3WTF6Thread10entryPointEPNS0_16NewThreadContextE (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #6  0x00007fa4f4eb41aa n/a (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #7  0x00007fa4f2d434cf start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
   #8  0x00007fa4f93912d3 __clone (libc.so.6)

   Stack trace of thread 4960:
   #0  0x00007fa4f938be9d syscall (libc.so.6)
   #1  0x00007fa4f83ed11b g_cond_wait_until (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #2  0x00007fa4f846aef3 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #3  0x00007fa4f84120db n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #4  0x00007fa4f8418bb1 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #5  0x00007fa4f2d434cf start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
   #6  0x00007fa4f93912d3 __clone (libc.so.6)

   Stack trace of thread 5025:
   #0  0x00007fa4f93869ef __poll (libc.so.6)
   #1  0x00007fa4f843c120 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #2  0x00007fa4f843d0c3 g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #3  0x00007fa4f4eb3d62 _ZN3WTF7RunLoop3runEv (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #4  0x00007fa4f4e54909 _ZN3WTF6Thread10entryPointEPNS0_16NewThreadContextE (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #5  0x00007fa4f4eb41aa n/a (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #6  0x00007fa4f2d434cf start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
   #7  0x00007fa4f93912d3 __clone (libc.so.6)

   Stack trace of thread 5026:
   #0  0x00007fa4f2d4a4bd pthread_cond_signal@@GLIBC_2.3.2 (libpthread.so.0)
   #1  0x00007fa4f4e51666 _ZN3WTF10ParkingLot13unparkOneImplEPKvRKNS_12ScopedLambdaIFlNS0_12UnparkResultEEEE (libjavascriptco>
   #2  0x00007fa4f4e487c6 _ZN3WTF13LockAlgorithmIhLh1ELh2ENS_14EmptyLockHooksIhEEE10unlockSlowERNS_6AtomicIhEENS3_8FairnessE >
   #3  0x00007fa4f4eb7b69 _ZN3WTF15BinarySemaphore6signalEv (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #4  0x00007fa4f4eb0301 n/a (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #5  0x00007fa4f4e54909 _ZN3WTF6Thread10entryPointEPNS0_16NewThreadContextE (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #6  0x00007fa4f4eb41aa n/a (libjavascriptcoregtk-4.0.so.18)
   #7  0x00007fa4f2d434cf start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
   #8  0x00007fa4f93912d3 __clone (libc.so.6)

   Stack trace of thread 4963:
   #0  0x00007fa4f93869ef __poll (libc.so.6)
   #1  0x00007fa4f843c120 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #2  0x00007fa4f843c1f1 g_main_context_iteration (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #3  0x00007fa4f947be5e n/a (libdconfsettings.so)
   #4  0x00007fa4f8418bb1 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #5  0x00007fa4f2d434cf start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
   #6  0x00007fa4f93912d3 __clone (libc.so.6)

   Stack trace of thread 4964:
   #0  0x00007fa4f93869ef __poll (libc.so.6)
   #1  0x00007fa4f843c120 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #2  0x00007fa4f843d0c3 g_main_loop_run (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #3  0x00007fa4f85acbc8 n/a (libgio-2.0.so.0)
   #4  0x00007fa4f8418bb1 n/a (libglib-2.0.so.0)
   #5  0x00007fa4f2d434cf start_thread (libpthread.so.0)
   #6  0x00007fa4f93912d3 __clone (libc.so.6)

   Stack trace of thread 5023:
   #0  0x00007fa4f93912c5 __clone (libc.so.6)
   #1  0x0000000000000000 n/a (n/a)
```

If it's helpful, when I stepped through the Gnome-Tweaks python script, this issue occurs on the very last line, "app.run(None)".

I'm unsure of what other logs would be helpful, let me know if there are any.

Edit: Want to specify I did try uninstalled and reinstalling

Edit: Tried uninstalling with pacman -Rndd and reinstalling

Edit: https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/879jyl/unable_to_start_gnomecontrolcenter/  libsoup is up to date but tried reinstalling, no dice.

Edit: I'm running Gnome 3.34.2, and I've tried launching in both Xorg and Wayland

Edit: Reinstalling the entire Gnome group also did not fix the issue.

Edit: Oddly enough, uninstalling, the rebooting, and THEN reinstalling allowed it to launch again, however this is not a solution since it'll probably happen again under the same circumstances